# CSS animation crashes Phonegap App on iPad only

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

My Phonegap App I am using High resolution images and zooming functionality using iScroll. But it looks blur so i got one solution add css translate. It solves my image blur issue but in iPad2 my App crashes due to this css transform.

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna,
Those specific CSS strings `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` are used to turn on *hardware acceleration*. At least, that is [what I read](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d) again and again. If you know that they are making you App crash, take them out. I don't see the issue.

The answer to your blurring, try something else - like [increasing your pixel density](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/common-techniques-in-responsive-web-design.html#fbid=UZJyfkvftFq).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me play with css..Hope I will get any solution.